# How to return int as server response?

Tags: java, networking, server

Is this the correct way to return an int from a server response?

```java
public static int getRequest2(String url) {
    String intresponse = "";
    int result = Integer.parseInt(intresponse);
    try {
        intresponse = Request.Get(url).execute().returnContent().asString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

static int urlr(){
    return getRequest2("http://random.com");
}
```

I'm used to return string response, I'm a little lost on how to convert it. I tried to convert the string into an int.

Comment: what response do you expect? 200 OK, or a random number?

Comment: Why convert it at all? Why not just return the required value? `return 1;` for example. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Just because you yourself can't understand it does not mean someone else can't. There was no need for the down vote. If you cant understand what's going on here then obviously you can't help me.

Comment: What can't be understood here is how you think you can convert `""` to a number. It *isn't* a number.